CDK Step function transition between state
guys.
Could anyone tell me how to achieve similar architecture for the step function leveraging CDK?
Particularly I am stack on transition between HEAD OBJECT and SUCCED state.
It seems that it only allows me define everything via next() like this:
  const stateMachineDefinition = describeDbCluster
    .next(headObjectS3)
    .next(lambdaInvokeRetrieveSSM)
    .next(distributedMap)
    .next(pass)



But my logic is to move from headObjectS3 to the end (pass) state.
Because these two: headObjectS3 and distributedMap should be executed only in case of the catch, which i defined like this
lambdaInvokeRetrieveSSM.addCatch(distributedMap, {
        errors: ["States.ALL"]
      })

Thank you in advance for helping me.
Greeting.
Here is the img:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/0k5pjMHC.png
